# need a button to bring up certain datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, dataset

Hey guys I need a button to bring up a certain Database in datagrid view. Is it possible that it can bring it up on the same form and not be directed to a new form??

This is what I have done so far.

I've created a form with 3 buttons - button1, button2, button3.

I've got three databases and have created the dataset for each - let's just call them datasat1, dataset2 and dataset3.

Now I know i can drag the dataset onto the page in data grid view. but I don't want to have just one on the page. I want it to change and show the dataset depending on the button clicked. So button1, when clicked must display dataset1, and so on.

Very new to this, sorry.

OH and this is what I managed to come up with so far(though I think it might be terribly wrong)

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.database1DataGridView.Visible = true;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.database2DataGridView.Visible = true;
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.database3DataGridView.Visible = true;
    }
```

the original visibility is set to false for each dataviewgrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you could try to bind the dataset into the gridview datasource in the button click event, just like Guru Stron said...

something like this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (DataTable dt1 = getDataTable1())
    {
        using (DataSet ds1 = new DataSet())
        {
            ds1.Tables.Add(dt1);
            YourDataGridView.DataSourceID = null;
            YourDataGridView.DataSource = ds1.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            YourDataGridView.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

or, if you could just modify your code a bit:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    database1DataGridView.Visible = true;
    database2DataGridView.Visible = false;
    database3DataGridView.Visible = false;
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    database2DataGridView.Visible = true;
    database1DataGridView.Visible = false;
    database3DataGridView.Visible = false;
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    database3DataGridView.Visible = true;
    database1DataGridView.Visible = false;
    database2DataGridView.Visible = false;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change 'DataSource' of your 'DataGridView' in button click handlers

```
button1.Click += button1_Click    

void (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _yourDataGridView.DataSource = dataset1;
    _yourDataGridView.DataMember = "TableName"; // table you want to show
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx

Comment: ok I'm still missing something Error The name '_yourDataGridView' does not exist in the current context

Comment: that's the error I get, I can only see it in metadata if I say "go to definition"

Comment: It's example name. Use your DataGridView name, like this.database1DataGridView ( of course the same one in all 3 button click handlers) And instead of "TableName" you need to use your table name, or write `_yourDataGridViewName.DataSource = dataset1.Tables[0];` without setting `DataMember`

Comment: Yes, haha, I'm new but not that new. I did replace the "_yourDataGridView" with my specific datagrid view name. But I haven't decalred it or anything yet. Should I?

Comment: You updated code in question works? If "yes" just  use one of the grids names from there

Comment: you need to add DataGridView with designer or declare it and then add to the form manually))